# how to redirect the user to login page spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to ***spring mvc***. I have a web application I would like to redirect user to login page when he clicks to a button in a html page, then when he logs in, I would like to send him back to the link he had originally clicked.I added a class called **MyAccessDeniedHandler** to the configuration package but i didn't know what to do then .

Comment: Is there any code that you tried?!

Answer (score 0):

yes Kenny Tai Huynh i tried this one :

```
@Component("myAccessDeniedHandler")
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    //@Qualifier("myRequestCache")
    //private RequestCache myRequestCache;

    public MyAccessDeniedHandler() {
    }



    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
            org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!arg1.isCommitted()) {
            arg0.getRequestDispatcher("/signin").forward(arg0, arg1);
        }
    }


}
```